# jenkins can ssh to another user, but pgp still thinks its the jenkins user

Tags: jenkins, encryption, ssh

I have a jenkins job that uses ssh to connect to the scheduler user on a quartz server; it can restart quartz as the scheduler user, and the processes and libraries appear to be owned by the scheduler, but whenever an encrypt/decrypt task is run, it thinks it's being called as the jenkins user instead of the scheduler.

ID and env indicate that the remote shell is running as the scheduler user - why does the encrypt task look to the jenkins .pgp directory?  The only way for me to fix this is to ssh to the box myself, sudo to the scheduler, and restart the jobs.  How do I get jenkins to emulate this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to record your own private key in Jenkins, through the [JENKINS SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin).

That way, Jenkins would be able to use your own SSH credential when  diong its SSH step, connecting to the quartz server as you instead of jenkins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; jenkins is successfully connecting to scheduler@server via ssh.  It's looking and acting like the scheduler user, so that all appears to be correct.  It's the encrypt/decrypt job run by the scheduler that seems to pick up the jenkins id instead of the scheduler id, even though `whoami`, `id`,`env`, and `pgp --key-list` all give appropriate output for the scheduler user.  I'm still missing something . . .

Comment: @Lutepisk Does `pgp --list-keys` also return the key for the alias jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

I finally spotted the source of my problem, and I'm so embarrassed - the scheduler user's home directory was actually owned by jenkins, with the scheduler user as the group owner.  No wonder pgp looked in the jenkins directory for its info.  I must have changed ownership to jenkins earlier when I was setting things up, but that wasn't a very good idea.

Thank you for responding - it is great to have some company when one is confused and needing a different perspective.

Comment: Good feedback, more precise than my answer. +1